# How to put "Move To" function in right-click window in Mac Lion

Tags: osx-lion

script for Move To function in right-click action window

Comment: Do you mean "Move Items Here" (⌥⌘V) in Finder?

Comment: yes. I was able to script Move To in Tiger and right-clicking over desktop file brought up window with Move To option at the bottom. Highlighted that and then Document window opened and I can select folder for where I want the file to be placed. Looking for same i Lion.